# Android Virtual Device Emulator freezes the OS

Tags: android, freeze, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run an Android Virtual Device (called "`Android4.0.3`") on Windows 7 64-bit. However, whenever I start it, it ends up completely freezing the computer (no mouse/keyboard input seems to be accepted). My music kept playing in the background, though.

Is there any way to run the device without freezing up Windows?

Comment: After how many minutes does it freeze?

Comment: Ahh the [scary music] Android Emulator. It is hard to tell why this is happening because of so many factors. Has this happened before, if do, with Android 4.0.3? Did you download any new software on your computer. The first thing I do when I have any avd trouble is to make sure me ad plug-in is up to date in eclipse.

Comment: @MarcinS. It freezes instantaneously after the progress bar goes away.

Comment: Try using an emulator with an other platform e.g API Level 10. If this does not work eather, then you did install or setup something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comodo Firewall's Defense+ was messing things up. IIRC, the driver runs at the kernel level, thus giving it the ability to totally freeze up the computer.

To fix this:

1. Right click the Comodo Firewall icon in the taskbar.
2. Under "Defense+ Security Level", select "Training Mode".
3. Be sure to switch it back to what it was before once you're done running the virtual machine *at least once*.

Still not working?

1. Right click the Comodo Firewall icon in the taskbar.
2. Click on "Open..."
3. Click on "Defense+"
4. Click on "Trusted Files"
5. Look for the AVD directory and remove those entries; **or**, simply click on purge.